# pygame add object with mouse click

Tags: python, pygame, boids

Trying to add more boids by using mouse click ingame.

```
elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
         self.boids_group.add(boids.Boids(rect=pygame.Rect(random()*self.width, random()*self.height, 40, 40)))
```

I get an error msg that there is no object Boids in Boids, however this is the method i am adding boids to the game at start.

```
self.boids_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
        for i in range(cfg.boidNum):
            self.boids_group.add(boids.Boids(rect=pygame.Rect(random()*self.width, random()*self.height, 40, 40)))
```

And the cfg.boidNum is set to 19 at start, and its adding 19 boids, but not adding more when i push the mousebutton.

If anyone can guide me in the right direction....

Comment: Can you post more code for context? What exactly is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

The error msg i get when i try running is: line 69, there is no object Boids in Boids, line 69 ref to the mouse input line.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from random import random
from pygame.locals import *
import boids, predator, diver, pygame, sys
import config as cfg

bgimage = pygame.image.load("ramfjord.png")

class Ramfjorden:

    def __init__(self, width=1024, height=760):
        pygame.init()
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height))
        pygame.display.set_caption('Ramfjorden')

    def loadSprites(self):

        self.predator_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
        for i in range(cfg.predatorNum):
            self.predator_group.add(predator.Predator(rect=pygame.Rect(random()*self.width, random()*self.height, 70, 70)))

        self.boids_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
        for i in range(cfg.boidNum):
            self.boids_group.add(boids.Boids(rect=pygame.Rect(random()*self.width, random()*self.height, 40, 40)))

        self.diver_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.diver_group.add(diver.Diver(rect=pygame.Rect(300, 300, 150, 231)))

    def collision(self, sprite1, sprite2):
        if sprite1 == sprite2:
            return False
        else:
            return pygame.sprite.collide_circle(sprite1, sprite2)

    def mainLoop(self):
        fps = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.loadSprites()

        while True:
            self.screen.blit(bgimage, (0,0))
            self.predator_group.draw(self.screen)
            self.boids_group.draw(self.screen)
            self.diver_group.draw(self.screen)

            for predator in self.predator_group.sprites():
                predator.update(ramfjord=self)
            for boids in self.boids_group.sprites():
                boids.update(ramfjord=self)

            for predator in self.predator_group.sprites():
                predator.swim(ramfjord=self)                
            for boids in self.boids_group.sprites():
                boids.swim(ramfjord=self)

            spriteHitList = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(self.predator_group, self.boids_group, False, True, collided=self.collision)

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    exit()
                    sys.exit()

                elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                        pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(QUIT))

                elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                    self.boids_group.add(boids.Boids(rect=pygame.Rect(random()*self.width, random()*self.height, 40, 40)))

            pygame.display.update()
            fps.tick(30)  


def main():
    ramfjord = Ramfjorden()
    ramfjord.mainLoop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```